# Trying to make a form with 2 inputs

Tags: django

I have two different forms in my register page as the one to one relationship in one of the model will show a drop down box therefore I am using the second models field where the user will have to input the field.

How would I make it so when the forms are valid, the 'SNI' will save to the first form and not the second.

Model

```
from asyncio import FastChildWatcher
import email
from pyexpat import model
from xxlimited import Null
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class userCouncil(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, userID, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Email is required")
        user = self.model(userID = self.normalize_email(userID))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, userID, password):
        user = self.model(userID = self.normalize_email(userID))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



             

class sni(models.Model):
    SNI = models.CharField(max_length=256, primary_key=True)
    Used = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    password = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'SNI'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.SNI

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    userID = models.EmailField(primary_key= True ,max_length=256, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateOfBirth = models.DateField(max_length=8, null=True)
    homeAddress = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sni = models.OneToOneField(sni, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'userID'

    objects = userCouncil()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.userID


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Forms

```
import email
from pprint import isreadable
from pyexpat import model
from statistics import mode
from tabnanny import check
from xxlimited import Null
from attr import field
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms, widgets
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from matplotlib import use
from matplotlib.style import context

from .models import Account, sni

class createUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['userID','name','dateOfBirth','homeAddress','password1','password2', 'sni']


    def clean_userID(self):
        userID = self.cleaned_data['userID'].lower()
        u = self.cleaned_data['userID']
        check_existing = Account.objects.filter(userID=userID).exists()
        if check_existing:
            raise forms.ValidationError("The following userID already exists: " + u)
        else:
            return userID


class SNIForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = sni
        fields = ['SNI', 'Used']


class AccountAuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label = "password", widget = forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('userID', 'password')
```

Views

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from matplotlib import use
from matplotlib.pyplot import get
from matplotlib.style import context
from werkzeug import Request
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login as dj_login
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .forms import AccountAuthenticationForm, SNIForm, createUserForm

def login(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username').lower()
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, userID = username, password = password)
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm(request.GET)
        if user is not None:
            dj_login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboardPage')
        else:
            messages.info(request, "userID or password is incorrect")
    return render(request, 'base.html', context)

def registerPage(request):
    form = createUserForm()
    form2 = SNIForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = createUserForm(request.POST)
        form2 = SNIForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid:
            print(form2['SNI'].value)
            form.save()
            form2.save()
            userID = form.cleaned_data.get('userID')

            messages.success(request, "Account created for: " + userID)
            return redirect('loginPage')
    
    context = {'form' : form, 'form2' : form2}
    return render(request, 'register.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='loginPage')
def dashboardPage(request):
    context = {}

    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

In views please refer to the registerPage function. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What the first form can take is Sni_id.
There is no sni_id without first saving an sni instance.

What you can do is...
Save both forms

```
f=form.save()
f2=form2.save()
f2.instance.user = f.instance.id
```

UPDATE:

```
if form2.is_valid():
    sni = form2.data["sni"] 
    used = form2.data["used"]
    if SNI.objects.filter(sni=sni, used=used).exists()
    f=form.save()
```

Comment: I mean, in the SNI table, there will already be existing values so if it is equals one of the values in the SNI table, the form2 will be valid and saved to form 1

Comment: If i understand correctly, Then there's no need saving form2. Let me update

Comment: This does not work as sni = form2.fields["sni"]  returns an pointer to a address where the value is held

Comment: access the form data instead. check answer

Comment: This works however, when I save. The data is saved however the SNI field is shown as empty and doesn't save